# failed to upload image in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, nestjs-config

I am newbie in backend especially nodejs, I am using nestjs as framework. I want to make the name of my uploaded file `https://mydomain/files/example-image.png`, but I get an error like this:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
open 'C:\***\***\***\nestjs-learning\files\http:\localhost:3001\files\9795f8f8147410d8fa07a4de5a92e0678.png'
```

and here is my code to name the file:

```
FileInterceptor('image', {
  storage: diskStorage({
    destination: './files',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const randomName = Array(32)
        .fill(null)
        .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 16).toString(16))
        .join('');
      return cb(null, `http://localhost:3001/files/${randomName}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
    },
  }),
}),
```

Is this way wrong? Is there a specific way to name the file?
Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you add the url-path in file name
try this

```
      FileInterceptor('image', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './files', // path whare save the files
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          const randomName = Array(32)
            .fill(null)
            .map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 16).toString(16))
            .join('');
          return cb(null,`${randomName}${extname(file.originalname)}`); // return only file name
        },
      }),
    }),
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i want to get output like this
http://localhost:3001/files/image.png what should i do bro?

Comment: you need to make your controller read the assets in files folder
see how here https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static